# Vagrant up produces an error resulting from the update of chef to 12.0

Tags: vagrant, chef-solo, cookbook

I am trying to create a small cloud using cloudstack platform. In order to do so I used devcloud4 to get my hypervisor and NFS service that is needed for the datacenter implementation. I am trying to get a development environment where I am running cloudstack management server from my machine and having the other parts (hypervisor and NFS storage as VM machines). The problem I am facing now is that I am not able to get all the parts needed from devcloud4 which is in this case the NFS service.

devcloud4 simplifies getting a full Apache cloudstack environment through using vagrant in order to create the required VMs. Since the update of Chef to 12.0 I am getting an error message whenever I run `vagrant up` using the advanced installation ( Not the binary installation advanced which is working fine). The issue is that when loading the co-nfs cookbook the chef run process exits unsuccessfully. Below is the error message I am getting

```
management: [2014-12-11T12:22:12+00:00] ERROR: Cookbook loaded at path(s) [/tmp/vagrant-chef-2/chef-solo-1/cookbooks/co-nfs] has invalid metadata: The `name' attribute is required in cookbook metadata
management: [2014-12-11T12:22:12+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
Chef never successfully completed! Any errors should be visible in the
output above. Please fix your recipes so that they properly complete.
```

I have searched for the cause of this error and got that The name attribute thing is an intentional breaking change for chef 12.0. (opscode/chef#2435)

What I want to know is how to overcome this error. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Specify an older version of Chef to use with the --bootstrap-version option.

"knife solo (prepare/bootstrap) user@host -P password --bootstrap-version 11.16.4-1"